# how to rewrite args in a custom post type from your functions.php?

Tags: custom-post-types

I feel like this has been asked a million times, but I couldn't find anything close to the code I currently have.

```
function overwrite_gallery_slug( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'gallery') {

        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'team-murray';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'overwrite_gallery_slug', 10, 2 );
```

I need to add `with_front` and make it `false` but in my current code I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$rewrite` parameter of [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) accepts either a boolean or an array. We can overwrite the existing value of `$rewrite` with the array of our desired settings:

```
function overwrite_gallery_slug( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'gallery') {

            $args['rewrite'] = array (
                'slug'       => 'team-murray',
                'with_front' => false,
            );
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'overwrite_gallery_slug', 10, 2 );
```

Remember to flush permalinks after implementing this code.

Comment: Awesome. I was going to add `$args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;` below the `slug`, but your solution is much more clean. Thanks.

Comment: That's fine too. The solution I posted overwrites any existing value of `$rewrite`, so if that's a concern, adjusting the arguments individually (as you mentioned in your comment) would be preferable.